# In Uno, if a draw 4 is played and the player after next plays, does the player still have to draw 4

Tags: uno

Scenario player 1 plays a draw 4. Player 3 immediately plays a card.

Does player 2 still have to draw?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Point of order: player 3 cannot play their card until player 2 has drawn the four.

[Rulebook](https://www.unorules.com): "gameplay usually follows a clockwise direction" (The usually is there to handle the Reverse card). And "Wild Draw Four: [...] the next player also has to draw four cards as well as forfeit his/her turn."